# Flutter WhatsApp Sending Message Without User Interaction

Tags: flutter, sms, message, whatsapp

I'm new in flutter and I have trying to **search a way to send automatic message in background on whatsapp** and I couldn't find anything about it. I have found that it is possible to send an sms without user interaction in flutter but I want to send a message through whatsapp without user interaction at all..
Any one know if there is any way to do this ?
Thank you .

Comment: You have to think about why would Whatsapp (owned by Facebook) allow other developers to do that. They would have to have developed a way to allow other apps to invoke their app and send data to then be treated and send as a message to a specific user that could, or not, be on their user list. All of this happening in the background without the user knowing.

Comment: ok understood so the only way is to use SMS regular app

Comment: @kickass213 did u find any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use third-party services like Twilio Whatsapp API Service. It's a paid service. You can find all the documentation here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp
2. You can submit a contact form to WhatsApp directly https://developers.facebook.com/products/whatsapp they will contact you with their pricing.